# How to insert Indian Rupee symbol in JTextField in java?

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jtextfield

I am using a `JTextField` in which income is the input. So I have to display an `Indian Rupee` symbol in that `JTextField`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `"\u20B9"`.

Source: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9